# Having two images in the one site content type

Tags: library

Working on Sharepoint Online (2010 still not upgraded to 2013). 
I have created site content types with One image in them but need to be able to create a Site Content Type with the following columns:
Image Small (200px, 200px)
Image Big (700px, 400px)
Title
Description

I feel like Document Sets will be too hard for the users.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Nothing at all ?

Comment: How is Document Sets even related to this?

Comment: Because as far as I know the only way to have a content type with 2 image columns that both are uploaded from the local system is two actually have a group of content tyepes instead. And that would be a document set

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new content type and add another column for the other image - or add another column to your existing content type.

Comment: And would this be a 'publishing image' column for which the image has to be added through the library first and cannot be added directly from the local machine ?

Comment: The column itself would be a URL(image) column which simple stores the data - how you handle that column is up to you.